# TypeError: can't convert complex to float (Python3, solving for algebraic equations)

Tags: math, algebra

I have a simple formula for which I want to solve.  Assuming all variables other than x are known, I am trying to solve for x by the following folmula:  x = [(c-a)/a]^(1/b)
The initial equation was:  a * x^b - a = c, and that was my way for solving for x.

Below is a snippet of my code.

```
a = 5000
b = 5
c = 562

x = ((c-a)/a)**(1/b)
```

But for some reason it cannot handle it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/4eMfsF I'm pretty sure the error comes from later code that actually uses  `x`. Note that  `(c-a)/a` is negative; raising negative numbers to noninteger powers produces complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct formula is:
x = ((c+a)/a)**(1/b)

Comment: Holy cow, huge oversight on my part.  Thank you so much!